# Combine nodes from more MATCHes into single variable

Tags: neo4j, cypher

Using neo4j community edition 2.x. In Cypher, I need to MATCH nodes in (two) different ways, then combine these (two) sets of matched nodes into single set (one variable name). This set would then be used for further action.

[naive graph example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yKyfs.png) (I can't post images)

I would like to find all knowledge of the squirrel, including the knowledge shared by the groups she is member of. (example is fictional)

I imagine something like this:

```
MATCH (u:User{username:'squirrel'}), (:User{username:'squirrel'})<-[:MEMBER]-(g:Group)
WITH "COMBINATION OF u AND g" AS ug
MATCH (ug)-[:KNOW_HOW]->(k:Knowledge)
RETURN k.type
```

Outcome should be both "crack nuts" and "escape predators".

In the place of "COMBINATION OF u AND g" I tried variations on collect(u)+collect(g), EXTRACT, etc. Without success.

So far the simplest working way I found is using UNION.

```
MATCH (u:User{username:'squirrel'})-[:KNOW_HOW]->(k:Knowledge)
RETURN k.type
UNION
MATCH (u:User{username:'squirrel'})<-[:MEMBER]-(:Group)-[:KNOW_HOW]->(k:Knowledge)
RETURN k.type
```

This might solve this simple example, but is not good for more complex queries. I seek the solution for more general problem: MATCH several sets of nodes, glue them into single set (single variable) and continue with this new set.

Any ideas, please? Am I missing something basic? Or is this impossible? Thanks!

Something possibly similar on [grokbase](http://grokbase.com/t/gg/neo4j/129v4sz84k/cypher-how-to-make-a-cypher-query-matching-one-complex-path-or-another-one-or-both).

**edit:**

With [this hacky solution to similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22185906/3245761) I was able to solve the problem by extracting internal ids from collection of nodes:

```
MATCH (u:User{username:'squirrel'}), (:User{username:'squirrel'})<-[:MEMBER]-(g:Group)
WITH [x in collect(u)+collect(g)|id(x)] as collectedIds MATCH (ug) WHERE id(ug) in collectedIds
MATCH (ug)-[:KNOW_HOW]->(k:Knowledge)
RETURN k.type
```

Could it be done any better?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only general solution I found so far:

- match required starting points (with different names)
- collect internal ids of starting points
- match the starting points with collected ids (now the starting points have single name)
- do whatever action you need to do with the starting points

Now the code itself:

```
MATCH (u:User{username:'squirrel'}), (:User{username:'squirrel'})<-[:MEMBER]-(g:Group)
WITH [x in collect(u)+collect(g)|id(x)] as collectedIds MATCH (ug) WHERE id(ug) in collectedIds
MATCH (ug)-[:KNOW_HOW]->(k:Knowledge)
RETURN k.type
```

Answer (score 4):

At least since Neo4j 3.0 you can use variable-length pattern matching to solve this issue. Simply set explicitly the minimum length to 0 and move the label test to a separate WHERE clause:

```
MATCH (:User {username:'squirrel'}) <-[:MEMBER*0..1]- (ug)
WHERE ug:User OR ug:Group
WITH ug
MATCH (ug)-[:KNOW_HOW]->(k:Knowledge)
RETURN k.type
```

Answer (score 2):

Not sure about the general case, but for this specific case, you might try to combine the two patterns into one as follows,

```
MATCH (u:User{username:'squirrel'})<-[:MEMBER*0..1]-()-[:KNOW_HOW]->(k:Knowledge)
RETURN k.type
```